# Привести датафрейм к единому числу строк по дате pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм вида:

```
                  Time  Open    High    Low     Close
  0 2019-12-30 05:50:00 1.12026 1.12051 1.12026 1.12036
  1 2019-12-30 05:55:00 1.12036 1.12037 1.12014 1.12027
  2 2019-12-30 06:00:00 1.12027 1.12029 1.12023 1.12029
  3 2019-12-30 06:05:00 1.12027 1.12028 1.12003 1.12006
```

В колонке Time по каждому дню бывают разные количества наблюдений, то есть разное количество строк в группировке по дню.

```
  df.groupby('Time').size().unique()
```

выдаёт такой ответ:

```
 array([218, 265,  24, 288, 264, 285,  36, 252,  35, 276, 287], dtype=int64)
```

Передо мной 2 задачи:

1. отобрать только те дни, наблюдения по которым начинаются с 00 часов 00 минут 00 секунд
2. привести количество строк по каждому дню к единому числу - 218, то есть те дни, в которых количество строк меньше 218 - удалить, а те, где больше 218 - обрезать с конца до 218 строк

Comment: 1). ,было бы неплохо получить хотя бы кусок исходных данных, на котором можно было бы воспроизвести ваши условия. 2). почему именно 218 ? судя по примеру данных, у вас записи за каждые 5 минут, а это 288 наблюдений в день, вроде.

Comment: 1) могу передать вам весь датафрейм, только как? 2) в разные дни количество наблюдений разное. Выше я привел информацию о том, сколько разных вариантов по количеству строк за день: есть какое-то количество дней с 288 наблюдениями, однако есть и 24 наблюдения за день и 35 и т.д. Количество 218 - столько минимально нужно для решения моей задачи

Comment: датафрейм. или его часть, можно выложить на файлообменник или в виде csv на google docs

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EbZJPLCOkww-e8JM4Kme1Ufhl7vnx9qO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Файл по этой ссылке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:
Исходный датафрейм:

```
                 Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
0 2019-12-30 05:50:00  1.12026  1.12051  1.12026  1.12036     189
1 2019-12-30 05:55:00  1.12036  1.12037  1.12014  1.12027     193
2 2019-12-30 06:00:00  1.12027  1.12029  1.12023  1.12029     113
3 2019-12-30 06:05:00  1.12027  1.12028  1.12003  1.12006     217
4 2019-12-30 06:10:00  1.12006  1.12021  1.12005  1.12019     143
...
```

Группируем и отбираем:

```
grp = df.groupby(df["Time"].dt.day)
res = pd.concat([group[:219] for index, group in grp if (group.iloc[0]["Time"].floor("D")==group.iloc[0]["Time"]) and len(group)>=218])
```

Тогда res будет:

```
                   Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
507 2020-01-02 00:00:00  1.12188  1.12190  1.12178  1.12189     131
508 2020-01-02 00:05:00  1.12189  1.12189  1.12180  1.12182      98
509 2020-01-02 00:10:00  1.12183  1.12183  1.12161  1.12162     242
510 2020-01-02 00:15:00  1.12161  1.12169  1.12157  1.12161     190
511 2020-01-02 00:20:00  1.12161  1.12166  1.12157  1.12160     234
...
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Только не понял что такое .floor("D") и как это работает?

Comment: в данном случае floor("D") - метод типа datetime - он показывает дату-время на указанное число, обнуляя все до начала дня. то есть, мы получаем значение для указанной записи на начало суток и сравниваем его с реальным значением записи. если они равны, то значит оригинальная запись приходится на полночь. что нам и надо.